How to compare different potential merge results?
I have a feature branch feature/foo and a development branch develop I want to merge the feature to.
I already did a code review at a later point. Now further changes have been pushed to feature/foo. Those consist of merges with the development branch.
How can I identify the differences of the potential merge commit to develop to the previous - already reviewed - state which has not actually be merged?

In other words, what are the changes between review 2 and review 1 which are relevant for the merge?
I encounter this regularly when reviewing code as part of pull requests (GitHub) or merge requests (GitLab) using the web interface. The solution may be outside such web interfaces as it shall only support the analysis.
Simply comparing changesets is not what I am looking for.
Because that would also generate differences for (irrelevant) changes which would not be touched by a merge.

The way to compare merge outcomes is to actually merge.

Merging upstream branches (develop) into feature branches is a big no-go in my book. It leads to all sorts of problems like the one you have here. Tell your developers to reset the feature branch to before the merge after they have tested the integration. If that's not possible because they need features from develop, that's a call for better branch organization.

You can:
checkout develop
git branch develop-temp
git checkout develop-temp
git merge foo
git diff develop foo

this will create a new branch from develop, an exact copy of it, check it out, merge foo and then check the diff. This would provide the information you need. If you like the result, then you may merge foo into develop too with the same result.

This answer does not regard the need to compare the current (potential) merge result with the previous potential merge result. The previous potential merge result was the basis for the previous code review. As shown by common merge/pull request tools.

Assuming the first review took place between the commits 0xf001 (feature/foo) and 0xDEF1 (develop). And the second review shall be between the commits 0xf002 (feature/foo) and 0xDEF2 (develop).
First identify the changes which have been introduced by the feature branch (note the three dots):

git diff --patch --cc 0xDEF1...0xf001 > patch1.diff
git diff --patch --cc 0xDEF2...0xf002 > patch2.diff

Now compare the differences:
diff -u patch1.diff patch2.diff

